# Define unique IDs for wso2.carbon: in deployment.yaml || Kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, wso2, unique-key

**Requirement:**
Need to assign two different id's for each pod in deployment.yaml for id parameter, wso2.carbon section.
i.e. wso2-am-analytics_1 and wso2-am-analytic_2

**SetUp:**
This deployment is a kubernetes deployment deployment.yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: wso2apim-mnt-worker-conf
  namespace: wso2
data:
  deployment.yaml: |
    wso2.carbon:
      type: wso2-apim-analytics
        
      id: wso2-am-analytics
        
      name: WSO2 API Manager Analytics Server
      ports:
          # port offset
        offset: 0
.
.
.
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: wso2apim-mnt-worker
  namespace: wso2
spec:
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      deployment: wso2apim-mnt-worker
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to necessarily have the ID as wso2-am-analytics_1 and wso2-am-analytics_2. This just has to be a unique value. Hence you can use something like the pod IP for this. If you are strict about the ID value you can create the config map based on a config file and then have some logic to populate the config files' ID field appropriately. If you use helm this would be pretty easy.

If you are ok to use some other unique value you can do the following. In WSO2 configs you can read values from environment variables, hence you can do something like this.

```yaml
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: ConfigMap
    metadata:
      name: wso2apim-mnt-worker-conf
      namespace: wso2
    data:
      deployment.yaml: |
        wso2.carbon:
          type: wso2-apim-analytics
            
          id: ${NODE_ID}
            
          name: WSO2 API Manager Analytics Server
          ports:
              # port offset
            offset: 0
   
# Then in the Deployment pass environment variable
env:
  -
   name: NODE_ID
   valueFrom:
     fieldRef:
     fieldPath: status.podIP
```